Does a passenger jet detect excessive weight in the tail after it's just landed?
My wife flew in on a BA jet yesterday and immediately after landing the pilot told the passengers that the tail was very heavy and that they needed to remove stuff before he'd taxi very far.  I've never come across this before.
Any explanations, please?

and then what happened? They threw stuff off on the runway? What do you mean remove stuff?
This is probably for weight and balance.

I'm guessing that the pilot felt that it took more pressure than usual to lower the nose during landing, and so he wanted some of the luggage and/or cargo removed from the rear of the plane. Perhaps he was concerned that the nose might pop up while taxiing?

Maybe something shifted in the cargo bay? I don't know, this doesn't sound right to me. Once the plane is fully on the ground, I can't see why there'd suddenly be a danger of tipping up.  There was a jetblue that did it a while back, but I thought that was blamed on failing to get the rear cargo bays empty before the passengers left (and/or emptying the front cargo). I can't see how it would just tip up during taxi.

@DarthPseudonym: If the pilots noticed that derotation took an unusual amount of force (indicating a tail-heavy aircraft), they might've wanted to make sure weight was getting taken out of the tail while they still had this fresh in their minds, rather than planning on just telling the ground crew to unload from the rear first once they reached the gate (and potentially forgetting about the tail-heaviness, and consequent increased-potential-for-tippiness-while-being-unloaded, during a long taxi in).

Without knowing the specific aircraft, could there have been a rear-of-CoG fuel tank that was expected to be functional so was filled with fuel, but once in flight it was not able to be emptied (pump failed, etc.) so that fuel mass was not able to be burned off or shifted to another tank, leading to an unexpected CoG farther back than normal?

If the plane were borderline unstable on the ground, is it possible or even likely that the usual front first deboarding could lighten the plane enough for it to tip the nose up?

If you'd provide the flight number, we could look up which specific aircraft was in use and offer more insight into possible scenarios.

Thanks to all for the informative comments.  It was flight BA 1334 on 24 Sept  LHR > NCL

@SkipMiller Certainly that's possible; see the JetBlue incident I mentioned from last year.

I would say the pilot was shooting his mouth off.

@SkipMiller Yes, that is 100% a thing that can happen with the 737-900ER if the tail-support stick isn't used: https://www.avweb.com/aviation-news/update-more-details-emerge-in-united-737-900-tail-strike-episode/

There is no scenario where that would make sense. If the Center of Gravity made the airplane controllable in the air, there is no condition that could make it "tippy" on the ground taxiing in. Otherwise the airplane would be at the bottom of a hole in the ground.
My guess is the announcement was to explain why the airplane was stopping for an extended period on a taxiway, likely to have a brake inspection done following an overheat indication in the cockpit. The idea would be to avoid alarming passengers as airport vehicles approach the airplane while stopped on the taxiway.
Just a theory as to the most plausible explanation.

There's a big difference between how far back the center of mass has to be to render the plane uncontrollable and how far back it can be before causing noticeably-interesting handling characteristics, though.  That's part of why the edge of the certified envelope is well short of the point at which LoC occurs.  (Also, even if the pilots noticed that the plane was tail-heavy enough to cause noticeable handling difficulties in flight, they can't really do anything about that before landing anyway - but they can at least wait to taxi until the problem's been resolved.)

Also, wouldn't news of a weight-and-balance exceedance be more worrying (being a much-more-serious situation) than news of hot brakes?  I know I'd be much more worried to hear that the flight I was just on'd had a dangerously-far-aft CoM than to hear that the brakes were hot.

Also also, a mild excessively-aft-CoM situation might've been trimmed out during most of the flight and only become noticeable by a need for increased pitch-control inputs during landing.

@Vikki As someone not in the aviation industry, overheated brakes sounds like a much bigger problem (danger! hot! fire! explosion!) than a balance issue (who cares its not like the plane can tip over right?). I'm aware that the actual impact of an imbalance is potentially higher than some overheated brakes, but most laypeople probably aren't. To a human, getting burned is a bigger issue than tripping.

There is one aircraft for which your first paragraph is not true, the 747-100/200/400. The takeoff and landing aft c.g. limit is 33.0% MAC. However, in addition to a main landing gear at 26.6% MAC, there is a body gear aft of the main gear. If that fails to extend, flight characteristics don't change other than a little less drag, but after landing and the c.g. is greater than 26.6%, there will be a moment to set the aircraft on its tail, rotating about the main gear. As I remember, the checklist action item is DO NOT ATTEMPT TO TAXI.

@Terry: I'm slightly worried at the implication that someone somewhere at some point must've actually tried to taxi in that situation, tilted back with the tail on the runway and the nose in the air, for them to put in that explicit warning...

@Terry Well that's a gear problem, not a C of G problem.

@Vikki There is something seriously wrong with an airplane that is within its CG range yet is in danger of tipping back on the ground.  On landing, the CG will be forward of the takeoff case because of fuel being burned off, unless it lands after only the center tank has been used. Once center tank fuel is consumed, CoG starts to move forward. In any case, the gear contact point must be aft of the aft CG limit. On airplanes with tail mounted engines, it's quite a ways back, so it doesn't tip when unloaded while full of fuel, which can require a larger tail surface than otherwise.

That first para is a bit strong - airworthiness depends on the relationship between the center of mass and the center of lift. Ground handling depends on the relationship between the COM and the position of the wheels, so there is no strong link between the two.

@JohnK: "unless it lands after only the center tank has been used" - perfectly plausible if they're tankering to avoid having to refuel at a destination with really-expensive fuel.

It's quite possible for an aircraft to be tail heavy on the ground without it affecting flight performance. Usually though this is temporary during loading (so the aircraft won't fly like that, thus flight performance is not affected). That's why some aircraft have built in tail stands, and for some others temporary ones are sometimes used during loading or maintenance.

@Vikki in any case the aircraft's CofG must remain at or forward of the aft limit for the entire flight.

Many thanks for all the comments, many of which,, I confess, went over my head but I will learn.    I grilled my wife for more details.  "Did she think the plane landed faster than normal?  Yes.   'Did she think the pilot braked harder than normal?  Yes" but bear in mind she is not a regular flyer.   A couple of men rolled up but nothing was off-loaded per se.  Some minutes later, the pilot informed the cabin that he had rung ahead to get the luggage off-loaded before the passengers".

But when they got to the jetway, no luggage was off-loaded but passengers did exit by both front and rear exits.I have no idea if that information helps or hinders.

Is there any possibility that the landing itself is what caused the mass to shift? For example, if there had been something heavy in storage, and a cable failed such that it then slid backwards during the flare, and then maybe got wedged on something that prevented it from sliding forward during the braking?

@countryman Generally when an airplane has to stop on a taxiway after landing and a vehicle drives up while out on a taxiway somewhere, it's almost certainly to check out the brakes after an overheat indication in the cockpit. It's to check for signs they may be on fire or at risk of fire and you want that done while away from the terminal or other airplanes. If there was a brake fire, the capt would likely order an emergency evacuation on the spot. Could be something else, but if you made me bet $100, I'd bet on that.

@TheGuywithTheHat "who cares its not like the plane can tip over right?" Some planes absolutely can tip over if unloaded improperly: https://www.avweb.com/aviation-news/update-more-details-emerge-in-united-737-900-tail-strike-episode/

@John K.    I know all about that !!  My wife and I were flying back to LGW one time and on final approach.  I noticed that the flaps hand't extended and mentioned as much to the missus.  "Is that a problem?" she asked.  "No, just that we will land faster than normal".  A few seconds later the pilot said the very same thing over the cabin loudspeakers.   Sure enough, we came in like the clappers ...most exciting..and at the end of the runway, the pilot taxied off it and announced that 'there isn't a spare gate' and so we will be waiting here for ten minutes.

I whispered to my wife " That's not true.  He's waiting to see if the brakes catch fire".  Sure enough, a few seconds later, couple of fire tenders arrived to keep an eye out.    Ten minutes passed, we headed off the the terminal and on arrival found another fire-engine waiting there 'just in case'.    I was rather impressed by the professionalism shown at LGW that day.

@countryman You weren't in a one of the little 50 seat CRJ200s were you? Flapless landings were quite common. The reference speed at typical landing weight (the speed you fly the last part of the approach at) was over 160kts, about 184 mph.

LOL...no, full blown passenger jet.

There are too few details in the question to actually pin point the problem and eliminate extreme cases, but...

Does a passenger jet detect excessive weight in the tail

This situation can be sensed indirectly.
There is a switch in the shock absorber mechanism of the nose landing gear (sometimes called the squat switch) which closes when enough force is applied to the shock absorber, which happens when the aircraft in fully landed (a status known as "weight on wheels"). This switch can be prevented to close for different reasons, for example if there is too much weight at the rear of the aircraft, the main wheels, located under the belly, at the level of the wing, acting as a pivot.
In this case some systems may be prevented to be used and the ground proximity warning system, may issue alerts. As there is not enough weight on the nose gear, it's directional  effectiveness may be unknown, it can be be considered unsafe to use.

the pilot told the passengers that the tail was very heavy and that they needed to remove stuff

Some mass in the holds have moved rearward or there is a fuel mass imbalance in the tanks, the forward tanks are empty, but rear tanks are still full. Such fuel imbalance may have been created by a malfunctioning fuel pump in tanks aft of the main wheels.

Center fuel tanks on a A321 neo, for extended operations. Source.
In that case the crew may want to remove some mass from the aft cargo hold, or move some mass aft of the wing to a location forward.

It's hard to say what could have happened here -- assuming the pilot was being honest about what was going on, he probably felt an unusual tail-heaviness while landing and it was disturbing enough that he didn't want to go very far in that state.
How could tail-heaviness occur? There are a couple of things I can think. Based on the route you mentioned in your comment, you were probably in an Airbus A320, which (like many airliners) has a small fuel tank in the tail called a trim tank. Fuel can be shifted into the tail to adjust the aircraft's balance, but if the pump broke down, it's possible they couldn't remove fuel from the trim tank when needed, leading to an unusually heavy rear. Alternatively, it's possible something in the cargo hold shifted and they weren't comfortable with continuing until that was inspected. That shouldn't happen, but it's hard to say anything is impossible.
It seems unlikely to me that the imbalance would be enough that the airplane might tip up during taxiing, but pilots are often conservative with the safety of their plane, so if anything felt off, they would likely rather get it inspected just off the runway rather than take even a small risk of a multi-million-dollar accident. A small delay out of an abundance of caution is a small price to pay.
This may be related to the fact that just about a year ago (in October of 2023), a JetBlue airliner overbalanced and tipped up while sitting quietly at the gate, causing an expensive tail-strike:

The incident was blamed on failure to remove some heavy cargo from the rear bay before the passengers and forward cargo bays had cleared, which led to the bizarre situation. As I recall, the rear cargo door was stuck, leading to delays in unloading.

Flight history on FR24 confirms that the airplane in question was an A320.

Regardless of the status of the trim tank, a CoG far enough aft to create a risk of tipping backward on the gear after landing, the gear being aft of the CofG limit, would have been at best neutrally stable or unstable in flight. You would never certify such a design.

Yeah, I'm thinking something felt weird on landing and the pilot, possibly with JetBlue in his head, just decided it was safer to get it checked before doing anything else.
